# Using two lists to define a variable in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that have a relationship with each other. List1 is descriptors and List2 is rankings of those descriptions

```
list1 = ["String1", "String2", "String3"]

list2 = ["2", "1", "3"]
```

What I want to be able to do is create variables that link these up. So if I want to print ranking number 1, I would get what was originally `string2`.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: A dictionary! See `help(dict)`. To get one out of those two lists, you can use `dict(zip(list1, list2))`. Or perhaps `dict(zip(list2, list1))`.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary, such as

```
content = {"2":"String1", "1":"String2", "3":"String3"}
print content["1"]
```

If you would like to generate the dic from list, you could:

```
content = dict((key, value) for (key, value) in zip(list2, list1))
```

Thanks to @minitech, a much more beautiful statement would be:

```
content = dict(zip(list2, list1))
```

Comment: The OP is starting with lists.  Show how to create the dict from the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dictionary. Dicionaries contain key:value pairs:

```
rankings = {"1":"String2", "2":"String1", "3":"String3"}
```

then you can access the elements like:

```
print rankings["1"]
```

it will print

```
"String2"
```

But how to create this dictionary? Use a `for` loop (assuming `list1` and `list2` have the same length)

```
rankings = {} # Create empy dicionary
for i in range(len(list2)): # Loop 'n' times, where 'n' is the length of the lists
    rankings[list2[i]] = list1[i]
```

**Note:** Depending in your implementation, you could just use a number, instead of a `string` as *key* in the dictionary:

```
rankings = {1:"String2", 2:"String1", 3:"String3"}
```

Comment: The OP is starting with lists.  Show how to create the dict from the lists.

Comment: Im importing these from excel files. So each list represents a row from the excel file. How would I go about merging into a dictionary from that excel input format?

Comment: See edit, this solution works based in the lists you gave as example.